# entity framework multi column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In sqlcommand I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cliente c
    LEFT JOIN abono a on
        c.idcliente = a.idcliente
        and (a.estatus = 1 or a.estatus = null)
    LEFT JOIN usuario u on
        a.creadopor = u.idusuario
WHERE c.estatus = 1
```

We know this is not the same than this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cliente c
     LEFT JOIN abono a on
         c.idcliente = a.idcliente
     LEFT JOIN usuario u on
         a.creadopor = u.idusuario
WHERE c.estatus=1
      and (a.estatus = 1 or a.estatus = null)
```

How can I do the first query in entity framework?

the second query in entity framework is it

```
from c in Conexion.conexion.conect.cliente
join a in Conexion.conexion.conect.abono
on c.idcliente equals a.idcliente into alj
from a in alj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join u in Conexion.conexion.conect.usuario
on a.creadopor equals u.idusuario into ulj
from u in ulj.DefaultIfEmpty()
where c.estatus == 1
&& (a.estatus == 1 || a.estatus == null)
```

but i could not get the first query

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your model.

Comment: @NunoCarmo i got the second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
from c in Conexion.conexion.conect.cliente
join a in Conexion.conexion.conect.abono.Where(x.estatus == 1 || x.estatus == null)
on c.idcliente equals a.idcliente into alj
from a in alj.DefaultIfEmpty()
join u in Conexion.conexion.conect.usuario
on a.creadopor equals u.idusuario into ulj
from u in ulj.DefaultIfEmpty()
where c.estatus == 1
```